After rendering the modal, the screen becomes unresponsive to touch interactions
       <Modal transparent visible={show} onRequestClose={() => setShow(false)}>
        <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
          <MonthPicker
            onChange={onValueChange}
            value={date}
            locale="en"
            mode="number"
            autoTheme={false}
            maximumDate={new Date(9999, 11, 31)}
          />
        </View>
      </Modal>

In Android, when rendering a Modal with show = true, the Modal appears, but nothing is clickable, as if a transparent layout is overlaying the screen. Pressing the back button once makes the MonthPicker inside the Modal usable, and pressing it again closes the modal entirely. When I check the logs, it shows "Show: false" after pressing back, yet the modal does not close in one step.
I want the modal to be rendered with show = true, allowing normal touch interactions immediately after it appears. Additionally, I would like the modal to close with a single press of the back button, without requiring multiple presses.
